# How to stop Webpage from coming out of fullscreen in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, fullscreen

I'm trying to create an online exam portal, Here in the exam window, I want My users to force into fullscreen, and not get out of it until the exam is complete.
I've used the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) here to achieve the Fullscreen.

```
goFullScreen = () => {
    if(document.documentElement.requestFullscreen) {
        document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();        // W3C spec
      }
      else if (document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        document.documentElement.mozRequestFullScreen();     // Firefox
      }
      else if (document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen();  // Safari
      }
      else if(document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen) {
        document.documentElement.msRequestFullscreen();      // IE/Edge
      }
}
```

I've basically copied the code from W3schools.
I want to know how to prevent them to get out of fullscreen? I can return false on 'Esc' Keypress, but there are other ways. Also, I don't want them to open developer window (i.e the console).
What methods should I approach ??

P.S. I'm using React, if that matters.

Comment: Not something you can do in Javascript, but something like chrome has a Kiosk mode,.  And the only way out of fullscreen is Alt-F4..  This of course requires you have access to the machines, so you can create the shortcut to start Chrome in Kiosk mode.

Comment: Thanks, Didn't know about it.
But I guess this is very particular about chrome. I need to look for a global solution.
Anyway, thanks for your valuable help. Appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot prevent exit from fullscreen** until you make an electron app or you have access to their computer.

Something which you want to do is **against the privacy of the user**. You can catch the `esc` key but, **you cannot override the browser**.  You can do one thing, catch the `esc` key and **end the test if the `esc` key is pressed**.

(I used JQuery, you can use vanilla JS also)

```
if(document.fullscreenEnabled) {
    // browser is almost certainly fullscreen
    //Execute end test code here
}
```

Request to accept if this answer helps...

Comment: I understand what you tried to do here, but there's also an option to go out by clicking a cross in the screen, so that isn't of much use

Comment: I've updated asnwer the by referring to MDN Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/fullscreenEnabled